# React Native: where do Info.plist and AndroidManifest.xml pull variable values from?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

In my React Native app, I noticed that in my `Info.plist` and `AndroidManifest.xml`, there are references to certain variables, and I don't know where those variables are defined. For example:

In `Info.plist`, I have the following code:

```
<array>
    <string>${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}</string>
</array>
```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml`, I have the following code:

```
<data
    android:pathPrefix="/android/${applicationId}/callback"
    android:scheme="${applicationId}"
/>
```

**My Question:**

Where do `Info.plist` and `AndroidManifest.xml` get the values for `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` and `applicationId`, respectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Product Bundle Identifier` is derived from Build Settings->Packaging->Product Bundle Identifier in Xcode (Also shown on the General tab under "Bundle Identifier").  `applicationId` is defined in the `defaultConfig` section of the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Ok thank you (I don't have high enough reputation to upvote yet). Do you know if Product Bundle Identifier is somewhere in the code itself, or can I find it only in XCode?

Comment: I think it's probably in the xcodeproj file but it's easiest to edit in Xcode